# NSTextView Logging Fast Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, user-interface, logging, nstextview

I'm trying to use an NSTextView to display high frequency updated logs but it's locking up the UI.

All logs are created in a different queue and only the minimal required updates occur on the main queue so I'm not sure how I can make this more efficient. I feel like I'm getting a leak because memory increases slowly but steadily over time.

If I turn off locking the app runs with minimal stable memory usage.

This is the function which updates the UI on the main queue. LogMessages are stored in an array which is kept at a fixed length on a 'background' queue and the most recent item is pushed to this function.

```
func logsChanged(message: LogMessage) {

    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"            
    let dateString = formatter.stringFromDate(message.time)

    let log = "[\(dateString)] " + message.text + "\n"

    let attrs = [NSFontAttributeName : NSFont(name: "Courier New", size: 12.0)!]
    let attributedLog = NSMutableAttributedString(string: log, attributes: attrs)

    if let textStorage = self.logging.textStorage {

        textStorage.beginEditing()
        textStorage.appendAttributedString(attributedLog)
        if textStorage.length > LogMaxSize {
            textStorage.deleteCharactersInRange(NSMakeRange(0, attributedLog.length))
        }
        textStorage.endEditing()

        self.logging.scrollToEndOfDocument(nil)

    }

}
```

This is the code which calls UI update. I'm even slowing down updates by limiting to 20/sec

```
// do not let anything else write to the logs until this has completed.
    dispatch_barrier_async(logAddQueue) {
        let message = LogMessage(type: type, time: NSDate(), text: text)
        if self.logMessages.count > self.maxMessages {
            self.logMessages.removeLast()
        }
        self.logMessages.append(message)

        if type == LogMessageType.Send || type == LogMessageType.Receive {

            if NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(self.lastUpdatedUI) >= 0.05 {
                // updates interface so run on the main queue
                dispatch_async(GlobalMainQueue) {
                    self.delegate?.logsChanged(message)
                }
                self.lastUpdatedUI = NSDate()
            }

        } else {
            // updates interface so run on the main queue
            dispatch_async(GlobalMainQueue) {
                self.delegate?.logsChanged(message)
            }
            self.lastUpdatedUI = NSDate()
        }


    }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: How are you calling this method? In a block?

Comment: It's a delegate call... `dispatch_async(GlobalMainQueue) {
                        self.delegate?.logsChanged(message)
                    }`

Comment: Just a tip: formatters are *really* expensive to create. Move it out of `logsChanged` and see if your performance improves

Comment: Ah! I didn't know that, thank you. I'll give that a go.

Comment: is the self in the dispatch_asyn call a weak or unowned self? Otherwise you might create a retain cycle. Also you have a call to self in the logsChanged method that can create a retain cycle. All this can be the cause of the leaks.

Comment: So I've moved the formatter out to a static and that's made a massive difference, memory usage has dropped significantly. Kicking myself for not knowing how expensive they are. I've also taken out the call to self in logsChanged because that shouldn't have been there anyway. The dispatch_sync self is owned, so that should be fine. Even without my interval check I can still get the UI to respond with a slight delay which isn't surprising if I'm logging 2500/sec. Thank you all!